# Reasoning about Binomial distribution?

Tags: calculus, probability

A binomial distribution is a sequence of $n$ Bernoulli experiments - each with a probability $p$ of success. Then it is said in the book that I read that to derive the PMF for binomial distributions, we consider the probability of any specific sequence of k successes **and** n − k failures, which is is $p^k (1 − p)^{n−k}$.

So here is my question: Why don't we just consider the probability of $k$ successes? I mean, if you have $k$ successes, doesn't that automatically imply $n-k$ failures? So for example, I would just have used $p^k$ as the formula for a sequence of $k$ successes and $n-k$ failures.

Comment: To have *exactly* $k$ successes you must also have $n-k$ failures.

Comment: @saulspatz Exactly, so why not just use $p^k$ which gives you the probability of exactly $k$ successes?

Comment: $p^k$ is not the probability of exactly $k$ sucesses in $n$ attempts (and it is very easy to see this, since $p^k$ does not depend on $n$). $p^k$ alone is the probability of $k$ successes on $k$ attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete my comment: as pointed out by @saulspatz, the key issue is that in probability we prefer talking about the exact number of successes, because otherwise it brings a whole bunch of scenario that are difficult to sum up with one number.

For that reason, the binomial distribution is useful because it is elementary: it corresponds to counting the exact amount of successes when we repeat the exact same experience.

The probability for $k$ successes obviously depends heavily on the number of attempts, it is quite rare to get 100 tails in 100 attempts with a fair coin, while it is completely normal if you toss it 10 000 times. For that reason it is quite clear that the corresponding probability should depend on $p,k$ but also $n$.

Finally, you can look at this sequentially: to have 3 successes among three attempts you need first two successes, which corresponds to $p^2$ and then one failure with probability $1-p$. You can not leave $p^2$ here as it would correspond to the case where you have at least two successes since
$$ p^2 = p^3 + (1-p)p^2$$
(the first term corresponds to exactly 3 successes, the second one to exactly two successes).
Of course you also need to count the number of positions available for the two successes (which is where the binomial coefficient plays a role).

Comment: Thank you, sir!